# Cambiar valores de un campo JSON en Python

Tags: python, json

Estoy intentando crear un script en python para cambiar los campos id en varios JSON (concretamente una secuencia de 1 a 500), haciendo que dicho id sea incremente en 1 despues de cada actualización, es decir, que la primera Label tenga id 0 y la última del último JSON sea el número total de Labels.

La estructura del JSON es la siguiente:

```
{
    "name": "000491",
    "timestamp": 0,
    "index": 491,
    "labels": [
        {
            **"id": 3**,
            "category": "truck",
            "npoints": 33,
            "box3d": {
                "dimension": {
                    "width": 2.8299999999999996,
                    "length": 7.180645161292857,
                    "height": 4.5
                },
                "location": {
                    "x": -5.616574983598179,
                    "y": -28.93376637241976,
                    "z": 0.4500000000000004
                },
                "orientation": {
                    "rotationYaw": 0,
                    "rotationPitch": 0,
                    "rotationRoll": 0
                }
            }
        },
        {
            **"id": 4**,
            "category": "truck",
            "npoints": 7,
            "box3d": {
                "dimension": {
                    "width": 3.337499999999998,
                    "length": 16.829558541273105,
                    "height": 4.799999999999999
                },
                "location": {
                    "x": -5.0050164473684315,
                    "y": -56.41093039702491,
                    "z": 0.13000000000000028
                },
                "orientation": {
                    "rotationYaw": 0,
                    "rotationPitch": 0,
                    "rotationRoll": 0
                }
            }
        }, .........
```

Como dato, hay 500 JSON

Y mi código es el siguiente:

```
## fixes all ids in a sequence

import json

annotations_folder_source = 'directorio donde almaceno los JSON'

category = "car"

new_id = 0

data_fixed = {}
labels_fixed = []

int_frame = 1
end_frame = 500


init_json = int_frame - 1  
end_json = end_frame - 1

for i in range(init_json, end_json+1):
    num_zeros = 6 - len(str(i))
    f_name = '0'*num_zeros + str(i) + '.json'

    f_path_source = annotations_folder_source + f_name

    # load source and target files
    with open(f_path_source) as f_source:
        data_source = json.load(f_source)

    for labels in data_source['labels']:
        if (labels['category'] == category):
            labels['id'] = new_id
            new_id = new_id + 1
            labels_fixed.append(labels)

data_fixed = data_source
data_fixed['labels'] = labels_fixed

# Closing files
f_source.close()

 # Saved combined result overwriting f_target
with open(f_path_source, 'w') as f_source:   
    json.dump(data_fixed, f_source)
f_source.close()

print("END")
```

La salida del script no actualiza los JSON y no entiendo el por qué.

Comment: La escritura del fichero resultante no debería estar también dentro del bucle? Ahora mismo lo tienes fuera, por lo que solo escribirá el correspondiente a la última iteración. (Nota adicional: no necesitas los `.close()`, eso ya lo hace el contexto `with ...`)

Comment: Sí, cambié eso y parece que funciona. Digo parece porque itera muy lentos los json, pero asumo que la escritura está siendo bastante costosa para el portátil de empresa. Muchas gracias por el comentario y la ayuda :)